# Java chess board image not showing

Tags: java, swing, chess

I'm in the process of developing a chessboard, with an issue. I'm trying to use an image to represent a chess square. But the image isn't showing.

This is the code in question:

```
//Add a chess board to the Layered Pane 
chessBoard = new JPanel();
layeredPane.add(chessBoard, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
chessBoard.setLayout( new GridLayout(8, 8) );
chessBoard.setPreferredSize( boardSize );
chessBoard.setBounds(0, 0, boardSize.width, boardSize.height);

for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
JPanel square = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
chessBoard.add( square );

int row = (i / 8) % 2;
if (row == 0); 
JLabel panel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/Users/Downloads/pieces/EmptySquare.jpg") ); 
}
```

All that's being shown are pieces and no squares, thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think `"/Users/Downloads/pieces/EmptySquare.jpg"` is a real path. No drive?

Comment: The path isn't the issue, i had to edit the path in the question as it partly contains my name.

Comment: I know, just pointing it out. The issue is that you're not doing anything with the `JLabel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things...

First...

Your `if` statement is ending in `;`

```
if (row == 0);
```

This is effectively ignoring the statement altogether.

Second, you never seem to add the `panel` to the UI...

```
    //...
    JLabel panel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/Users/Downloads/pieces/EmptySquare.jpg") ); 
} // End of for-loop...
```

Consider using `ImageIO.read` instead of `ImageIcon` as it will provide more details if the image can't be loaded.  Take a look at [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details...